# Why isnt Bootstrap Grid working properly after my main header?

Tags: html, css, grid

Everything works fine in the main header section. What im trying to do is create a simple row with 3 columns after it but they are displaying as 3 different rows and not 1 row with 3 columns? Below is the code. It strange because the header section is working perfect! Thank you for any help and advice!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>The Beckwood - Scunthorpe</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=satisfy" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

    <div class="header-main">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >
                     <img src="assets/img/logo.png">

                </a>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">BOOK A TABLE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="hero">
            <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to The Beckwood.</h1>
            <p>The Beckwood is a family run pub located in scunthorpe offering quality homemade food, carverys, events and live sports.</p>
            <div class="btn btn-primary">View Menu</div>
            <div class="btn btn-primary">Book a table</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS CODE, MAYBE SOMETHING IN HERE IS EFFECTING IT?

```
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 90px;
  width: auto;
}

.logo {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
}
.header-main {
    color: white;
    background: url("../../assets/img/banner.png") no-repeat ;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

.header-main .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.header-main .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 300px;
    border: none;
}

.header-main .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.header-main .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
.header-main .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.header-main .nav>li>a:focus,
.header-main .nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.header-main .navbar-nav>li {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.header-main .navbar-nav {
   margin-top: 12px;
}

.header-main .navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.header-main .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
}


.header-main .hero {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.header-main .hero h1 {
    color: #FFB03B;;
    font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 36px;

}


.header-main .hero p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    font-size: 18px;
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.header-main .btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #fffbfb !important;
    outline:none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 18px 24px;
    transition:0.2s background-color;
}

.header-main .btn-primary:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.header-main .btn-primary:active {
    transform:translateY(1px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .header-main .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a{
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .header-main .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
        color: #ccc;
    }

    .header-main .navbar-collapse {
        margin-left: 20px;
        border-top: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .header-main .hero{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .header-main .hero h1{
        font-size: 42px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make minimal code.

Comment: Check your console, my bet is you have errors.

Comment: It looks like I have this error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: You'll have to post the error(s) you're seeing. I would imagine at least one is related to you putting the bootstrap cdn before the jquery cdn. Bootstrap requires jquery and will error if jquery isn't loaded first. You also seem to be loading jquery twice, with two different versions.

Comment: I have fixed all errors but the rows and collumns after the header-main are still not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the errors I posted in my latest comment, the real problem is that you're not specifying the size of each column. With bootstrap you have to specify how many grid columns each col will take up. Totalling 12 across. So for your code, you simply need to add a -4 to the class:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        One of three columns
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a simple example that explains it more on W3:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! I was under the illusion that they would automatically divide by 12 if they haven't got a size set. All errors are fixed and the code is working. Thank you Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap 3 so you need to specify column width like `col-sm-4` not `col-sm`. if you used Bootstrap 4 `col-sm` should be fine.